# What is the most efficient way of comparing two sets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, set, comparison

In Python3, What is the **least time-consuming** way of comparing two `Set`s `elements`**(Whether they have identical elements or not)**?

For example, I want a function named `compareSets` like below. How should I write code to make it work in the least time-consuming way?

```
def compareSets(a, b):
    # if (elements are identical)
    # return True

    # if (elements are not identical)
    # return False
    pass
```

Comment: what you mean by compare, do you need common elements, only number of common elements, different elements only number of different elements? and what have you done yourself?

Comment: @Drako I have edited some to be more specific I want to know whether they have the same members or not in both sets

Comment: Err... have you tried the obvious  `a == b` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To test if two sets are equal, use the equality operator (`==`). Here is an example from the REPL, taking advantage of iterable strings:

```
>>> set('a') == set('a')
True
>>> set('a') == set('b')
False
>>> set('a') == set('ab')
False
>>> set('ba') == set('ab') #Shows the sets are order-independent
True
```